# Can't enable Flash with the Camera2 Api

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-camera2

I want to enable flash on/off in my camera app, but it isn't working,

Here's the code:

**FlashActivity.java**

```
public class FlashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CameraManager mCameraManager;

    private String mCameraId;

    private Button mTorchOnOffButton;

    private Boolean isTorchOn;

    private TextureView textureView;
    SeekBar sb;
    TextToSpeech t1;
    private String cameraId;

    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;

    Bitmap src;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice=null;
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("FlashActivity", "onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash);
        sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        mTorchOnOffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_on_off);
        isTorchOn = false;


        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);

        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    freeze();
                    String toSpeak = "Camera Freeze";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } else {
                    updatePreview();
                    String toSpeak = "Back to Live Camera";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        });

        Boolean isFlashAvailable = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!isFlashAvailable) {

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlashActivity.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setTitle("Error !!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device doesn't support flash light!");
            alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // closing the application
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return;
        }
        mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mTorchOnOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (isTorchOn) {
                        turnOffFlashLight();
                        isTorchOn = false;
                    } else {
                        turnOnFlashLight();
                        isTorchOn = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                float scale = ((progress / 10.0f) + 1);
                textureView.setScaleX(scale);
                textureView.setScaleY(scale);
            }


            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }


        });


    }


    public void turnOnFlashLight() {

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void turnOffFlashLight() {

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, false);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    ArrayList rev;

    public void freeze() {
        Thread td = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bmp = textureView.getBitmap();
                rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                rev.add(bmp);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + rev.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try {
                            cameraCaptureSessions.stopRepeating();
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                });

            }

        });
        td.start();
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if (cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(FlashActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if (cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            //Check realtime permission if run higher API 23
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(isTorchOn){
            turnOffFlashLight();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(isTorchOn){
            turnOffFlashLight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(isTorchOn){
            turnOnFlashLight();
        }
    }



      }
```

---

**Here's what I get at LOG**

---

```
04-03 16:38:34.948 10905-10905/com.example.sumesh.myapplication W/System.err: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: The camera device is in use already
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:123)
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy0.setTorchMode(Unknown Source)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$CameraManagerGlobal.setTorchMode(CameraManager.java:884)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.setTorchMode(CameraManager.java:501)
    at com.example.sumesh.myapplication.FlashActivity.turnOffFlashLight(FlashActivity.java:204)
    at com.example.sumesh.myapplication.FlashActivity$5.onClick(FlashActivity.java:150)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
   }
```

---

I have used the linear layout instead of the `relativeIlayout`, but I
 am unable to figure out what thing is exactly posing the error,
 all the permissions are already defined in the android manifest,
 any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , Full code for taking picture using camera2 API , `Fragment_Camera4`

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment_Camera4 extends Fragment implements

        AspectRatioFragment.Listener {
    private View view;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;

    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    private static final int[] FLASH_OPTIONS = {
            CameraView.FLASH_OFF,
            CameraView.FLASH_ON,
    };

    private static final int[] FLASH_ICONS = {

            R.drawable.ic_flash_off,
            R.drawable.ic_flash_on,
    };

    private static final int[] FLASH_TITLES = {
            R.string.flash_auto,
            R.string.flash_off,
            R.string.flash_on,
    };

    private int mCurrentFlash;

    private CameraView mCameraView;

    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.take_picture:
                    if (mCameraView != null) {
                        mCameraView.takePicture();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_switch_camera:

                    if (mCameraView != null) {
                        int facing = mCameraView.getFacing();
                        mCameraView.setFacing(facing == CameraView.FACING_FRONT ?
                                CameraView.FACING_BACK : CameraView.FACING_FRONT);
                        if (facing == CameraView.FACING_FRONT) {

                            btn_flash_onOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            btn_flash_onOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case R.id.btn_flash_onOff:
                    if (mCameraView != null) {
                        mCurrentFlash = (mCurrentFlash + 1) % FLASH_OPTIONS.length;
                        btn_flash_onOff.setImageResource(FLASH_ICONS[mCurrentFlash]);
                        mCameraView.setFlash(FLASH_OPTIONS[mCurrentFlash]);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    ImageButton btn_flash_onOff;

    public Fragment_Camera4() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__camera4, container, false);
        mCameraView = (CameraView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        if (mCameraView != null) {
            mCameraView.addCallback(mCallback);

        }
        ImageButton fab = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.take_picture);

        ImageButton btn_switch_camera = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_switch_camera);

        btn_flash_onOff = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_flash_onOff);
        if (fab != null) {
            fab.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            btn_switch_camera.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            btn_flash_onOff.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCameraView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mCameraView.stop();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBackgroundHandler != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                mBackgroundHandler.getLooper().quitSafely();
            } else {
                mBackgroundHandler.getLooper().quit();
            }
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAspectRatioSelected(@NonNull AspectRatio ratio) {
        if (mCameraView != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ratio.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCameraView.setAspectRatio(ratio);
        }
    }

    private Handler getBackgroundHandler() {
        if (mBackgroundHandler == null) {
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("background");
            thread.start();
            mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
        }
        return mBackgroundHandler;
    }

    private CameraView.Callback mCallback
            = new CameraView.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraOpened(CameraView cameraView) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCameraOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraClosed(CameraView cameraView) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCameraClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(CameraView cameraView, final byte[] data) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken " + data.length);
            Toast.makeText(cameraView.getContext(), R.string.picture_taken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            getBackgroundHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/_saved_images");
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
                    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                    String final_path = myDir + "/" + fname;
                    OutputStream os = null;
                    try {
                        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        os.write(data);
                        os.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Cannot write to " + file, e);
                    } finally {
                        if (os != null) {
                            try {
                                os.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // Ignore
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("path", final_path);
                    bundle.putString("type", "picture");
                    Fragment_Post_Image_Detail post_image_detail = new Fragment_Post_Image_Detail();
                    post_image_detail.setArguments(bundle);
                    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragmentWithBackstack(post_image_detail);

                }
            });
        }

    };

}
```

Then `Cameraview` class
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Parcel;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompat;
    import android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class CameraView extends FrameLayout {

    /** The camera device faces the opposite direction as the device's screen. */
    public static final int FACING_BACK = Constants.FACING_BACK;

    /** The camera device faces the same direction as the device's screen. */
    public static final int FACING_FRONT = Constants.FACING_FRONT;

    /** Direction the camera faces relative to device screen. */
    @IntDef({FACING_BACK, FACING_FRONT})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Facing {
    }

    /** Flash will not be fired. */
    public static final int FLASH_OFF = Constants.FLASH_OFF;

    /** Flash will always be fired during snapshot. */
    public static final int FLASH_ON = Constants.FLASH_ON;

    /** Constant emission of light during preview, auto-focus and snapshot. */
    public static final int FLASH_TORCH = Constants.FLASH_TORCH;

    /** Flash will be fired automatically when required. */
    public static final int FLASH_AUTO = Constants.FLASH_AUTO;

    /** Flash will be fired in red-eye reduction mode. */
    public static final int FLASH_RED_EYE = Constants.FLASH_RED_EYE;

    /** The mode for for the camera device's flash control */
    @IntDef({FLASH_OFF, FLASH_ON, FLASH_TORCH, FLASH_AUTO, FLASH_RED_EYE})
    public @interface Flash {
    }

    CameraViewImpl mImpl;

    private final CallbackBridge mCallbacks;

    private boolean mAdjustViewBounds;

    private final DisplayOrientationDetector mDisplayOrientationDetector;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WrongConstant")
    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (isInEditMode()){
            mCallbacks = null;
            mDisplayOrientationDetector = null;
            return;
        }
        // Internal setup
        final PreviewImpl preview = createPreviewImpl(context);
        mCallbacks = new CallbackBridge();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mImpl = new Camera1(mCallbacks, preview);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            mImpl = new Camera2(mCallbacks, preview, context);
        } else {
            mImpl = new Camera2Api23(mCallbacks, preview, context);
        }
        // Attributes
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CameraView, defStyleAttr,
                R.style.Widget_CameraView);
        mAdjustViewBounds = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraView_android_adjustViewBounds, false);
        setFacing(a.getInt(R.styleable.CameraView_facing, FACING_BACK));
        String aspectRatio = a.getString(R.styleable.CameraView_aspectRatio);
        if (aspectRatio != null) {
            setAspectRatio(AspectRatio.parse(aspectRatio));
        } else {
            setAspectRatio(Constants.DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO);
        }
        setAutoFocus(a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraView_autoFocus, true));
        setFlash(a.getInt(R.styleable.CameraView_flash, Constants.FLASH_AUTO));
        a.recycle();
        // Display orientation detector
        mDisplayOrientationDetector = new DisplayOrientationDetector(context) {
            @Override
            public void onDisplayOrientationChanged(int displayOrientation) {
                mImpl.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientation);
            }
        };
    }

    @NonNull
    private PreviewImpl createPreviewImpl(Context context) {
        PreviewImpl preview;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
            preview = new SurfaceViewPreview(context, this);
        } else {
            preview = new TextureViewPreview(context, this);
        }
        return preview;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            mDisplayOrientationDetector.enable(ViewCompat.getDisplay(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            mDisplayOrientationDetector.disable();
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (isInEditMode()){
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
        // Handle android:adjustViewBounds
        if (mAdjustViewBounds) {
            if (!isCameraOpened()) {
                mCallbacks.reserveRequestLayoutOnOpen();
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                return;
            }
            final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                final AspectRatio ratio = getAspectRatio();
                assert ratio != null;
                int height = (int) (MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * ratio.toFloat());
                if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                    height = Math.min(height, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
                }
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            } else if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                final AspectRatio ratio = getAspectRatio();
                assert ratio != null;
                int width = (int) (MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) * ratio.toFloat());
                if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                    width = Math.min(width, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
                }
                super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        heightMeasureSpec);
            } else {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
        // Measure the TextureView
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        AspectRatio ratio = getAspectRatio();
        if (mDisplayOrientationDetector.getLastKnownDisplayOrientation() % 180 == 0) {
            ratio = ratio.inverse();
        }
        assert ratio != null;
        if (height < width * ratio.getY() / ratio.getX()) {
            mImpl.getView().measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width * ratio.getY() / ratio.getX(),
                            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        } else {
            mImpl.getView().measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height * ratio.getX() / ratio.getY(),
                            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        SavedState state = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState());
        state.facing = getFacing();
        state.ratio = getAspectRatio();
        state.autoFocus = getAutoFocus();
        state.flash = getFlash();
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setFacing(ss.facing);
        setAspectRatio(ss.ratio);
        setAutoFocus(ss.autoFocus);
        setFlash(ss.flash);
    }

    /**
     * Open a camera device and start showing camera preview. This is typically called from
     * {@link Activity#onResume()}.
     */
    public void start() {
        if (!mImpl.start()) {
            //store the state ,and restore this state after fall back o Camera1
            Parcelable state=onSaveInstanceState();
            // Camera2 uses legacy hardware layer; fall back to Camera1
            mImpl = new Camera1(mCallbacks, createPreviewImpl(getContext()));
            onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            mImpl.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop camera preview and close the device. This is typically called from
     * {@link Activity#onPause()}.
     */
    public void stop() {
        mImpl.stop();
    }

    /**
     * @return {@code true} if the camera is opened.
     */
    public boolean isCameraOpened() {
        return mImpl.isCameraOpened();
    }

    /**
     * Add a new callback.
     *
     * @param callback The {@link Callback} to add.
     * @see #removeCallback(Callback)
     */
    public void addCallback(@NonNull Callback callback) {
        mCallbacks.add(callback);
    }

    /**
     * Remove a callback.
     *
     * @param callback The {@link Callback} to remove.
     * @see #addCallback(Callback)
     */
    public void removeCallback(@NonNull Callback callback) {
        mCallbacks.remove(callback);
    }

    /**
     * @param adjustViewBounds {@code true} if you want the CameraView to adjust its bounds to
     *                         preserve the aspect ratio of camera.
     * @see #getAdjustViewBounds()
     */
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (mAdjustViewBounds != adjustViewBounds) {
            mAdjustViewBounds = adjustViewBounds;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return True when this CameraView is adjusting its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of
     * camera.
     * @see #setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)
     */
    public boolean getAdjustViewBounds() {
        return mAdjustViewBounds;
    }

    /**
     * Chooses camera by the direction it faces.
     *
     * @param facing The camera facing. Must be either {@link #FACING_BACK} or
     *               {@link #FACING_FRONT}.
     */
    public void setFacing(@Facing int facing) {
        mImpl.setFacing(facing);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the direction that the current camera faces.
     *
     * @return The camera facing.
     */
    @Facing
    public int getFacing() {
        //noinspection WrongConstant
        return mImpl.getFacing();
    }

    /**
     * Gets all the aspect ratios supported by the current camera.
     */
    public Set<AspectRatio> getSupportedAspectRatios() {
        return mImpl.getSupportedAspectRatios();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the aspect ratio of camera.
     *
     * @param ratio The {@link AspectRatio} to be set.
     */
    public void setAspectRatio(@NonNull AspectRatio ratio) {
        if (mImpl.setAspectRatio(ratio)) {
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current aspect ratio of camera.
     *
     * @return The current {@link AspectRatio}. Can be {@code null} if no camera is opened yet.
     */
    @Nullable
    public AspectRatio getAspectRatio() {
        return mImpl.getAspectRatio();
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables the continuous auto-focus mode. When the current camera doesn't support
     * auto-focus, calling this method will be ignored.
     *
     * @param autoFocus {@code true} to enable continuous auto-focus mode. {@code false} to
     *                  disable it.
     */
    public void setAutoFocus(boolean autoFocus) {
        mImpl.setAutoFocus(autoFocus);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the continuous auto-focus mode is enabled.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if the continuous auto-focus mode is enabled. {@code false} if it is
     * disabled, or if it is not supported by the current camera.
     */
    public boolean getAutoFocus() {
        return mImpl.getAutoFocus();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the flash mode.
     *
     * @param flash The desired flash mode.
     */
    public void setFlash(@Flash int flash) {
        mImpl.setFlash(flash);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current flash mode.
     *
     * @return The current flash mode.
     */
    @Flash
    public int getFlash() {
        //noinspection WrongConstant
        return mImpl.getFlash();
    }

    /**
     * Take a picture. The result will be returned to
     * {@link Callback#onPictureTaken(CameraView, byte[])}.
     */
    public void takePicture() {
        mImpl.takePicture();
    }

    private class CallbackBridge implements CameraViewImpl.Callback {

        private final ArrayList<Callback> mCallbacks = new ArrayList<>();

        private boolean mRequestLayoutOnOpen;

        CallbackBridge() {
        }

        public void add(Callback callback) {
            mCallbacks.add(callback);
        }

        public void remove(Callback callback) {
            mCallbacks.remove(callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraOpened() {
            if (mRequestLayoutOnOpen) {
                mRequestLayoutOnOpen = false;
                requestLayout();
            }
            for (Callback callback : mCallbacks) {
                callback.onCameraOpened(CameraView.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraClosed() {
            for (Callback callback : mCallbacks) {
                callback.onCameraClosed(CameraView.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data) {
            for (Callback callback : mCallbacks) {
                callback.onPictureTaken(CameraView.this, data);
            }
        }

        public void reserveRequestLayoutOnOpen() {
            mRequestLayoutOnOpen = true;
        }
    }

    protected static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {

        @Facing
        int facing;

        AspectRatio ratio;

        boolean autoFocus;

        @Flash
        int flash;

        @SuppressWarnings("WrongConstant")
        public SavedState(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
            super(source);
            facing = source.readInt();
            ratio = source.readParcelable(loader);
            autoFocus = source.readByte() != 0;
            flash = source.readInt();
        }

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeInt(facing);
            out.writeParcelable(ratio, 0);
            out.writeByte((byte) (autoFocus ? 1 : 0));
            out.writeInt(flash);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
                = ParcelableCompat.newCreator(new ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks<SavedState>() {

            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader) {
                return new SavedState(in, loader);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Callback for monitoring events about {@link CameraView}.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters")
    public abstract static class Callback {

        /**
         * Called when camera is opened.
         *
         * @param cameraView The associated {@link CameraView}.
         */
        public void onCameraOpened(CameraView cameraView) {
        }

        /**
         * Called when camera is closed.
         *
         * @param cameraView The associated {@link CameraView}.
         */
        public void onCameraClosed(CameraView cameraView) {
        }

        /**
         * Called when a picture is taken.
         *
         * @param cameraView The associated {@link CameraView}.
         * @param data       JPEG data.
         */
        public void onPictureTaken(CameraView cameraView, byte[] data) {
        }
    }

}
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorgrey">

    <com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/take_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_take_pic" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_switch_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_reset_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_flash_onOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_off" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Also DONT FORGET TO ADD RUNTIME PERMISSIONS in OnCreate()**